# Unable to get Braintree Client token in angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, braintree

I have created a plugin for brain-tree payment integration that gets load on run time therefore i have generated the client token on the server side c# class and i am trying to use that in my angular controller but unable to do so.
Is there any way that i can get my session variable or some thing like that in my angular controller from c# class? so that i will be able to create drop-in UI in angular ready function.
I want to acheive something like this:

```
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            var clientToken = "From_Server_Side";
            braintree.setup(clientToken , 'dropin', {
                container: 'dropin-container',
                paypal: {
                    singleUse: true,
                    amount: 10.00,
                    currency: 'GBP'
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: How are you using this in your angular view

Comment: I want to use the session variable from my class library project inside my MVC angular view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a JsonResult like this in your controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult client_token()
    {
        var gateway = config.GetGateway();
        var clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.Generate();
        return Json(clientToken, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and then in your angularjs you have to do

```
$scope.get_token = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/home/client_token'
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.client_token_string = data.data;
    })
}
$scope.get_token();
```

I put home hypothetically assuming that your doing it in home controller